# Illustrator object scaling problem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, vector, logo, text

When I scale up my design it seems to bend weirdly. I've only just started using Illustrator as I started a course in graphic design a week or so ago. Here's what it is doing.[[image: 1]]

[image]

To be fair, The shape I used to create the curved tick over the I in the word is not the best, But I'm not sure why that's happening. (Yes I'm using shift when scailing).

Comment: Are you using the Free Transform tool to scale? What happens when you right click and use Transform > Scale ?

Comment: is that a brush? the shape needs to be outlined, can you show it in outline mode?

Comment: It looks like one point isn't selected. Are you selecting using the direct selection tool? (The black pointer, *not* the white pointer)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason for this to happen as long as you have selected the object **with the Selection tool** (v). Whether you shift-drag or use Transform > Scale should not matter.